# Why can't I run a working PDO connection through terminal?

Tags: php, pdo, terminal

My working index.php that runs in a browser looks like this:

```
<?php
    $dbh = new PDO(...whatever
```

It works in a bowser just fine. I can do anything.

Running in terminal like:

```
shell> php index.php
```

I get some error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php(3): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'frekinpassword')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php on line 3
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, your unix_socket changed and you didn't change your php client php.ini

**First of all, get your unix_socket location.**

```
$ mysql -uroot -p
```

Enter your mysql password and login your mysql server from command line.

```
mysql> show variables like '%sock%';
+---------------+---------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                 |
+---------------+---------------------------------------+
| socket        | /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock |
+---------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Your unix_soket could be diffrent.

Then change your php.ini, find your php.ini file from

```
<? phpinfo();
```

You maybe install many php with different version, so please don't assume your php.ini file location, get it from your 'phpinfo';

Change your php.ini:

```
mysql.default_socket = /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock

mysqli.default_socket = /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock

pdo_mysql.default_socket = /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
```

Then restart your apache or php-fpm.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using `localhost` as the connection string for your MySQL database.  When MySQL sees `localhost`, it interprets that as "use a mysql.sock" file.  PHP is telling you it can't find that mysql.sock file.

The most likely cause for this is your web server and command line PHP are configured to use different `php.ini` files, and those `php.ini` files have differently configured `mysql.sock` files. You can find your web server `php.ini` file(s) by running

```
phpinfo();
```

from a PHP file loaded via the web server.  You can find your command line `php.ini` file(s) by running the following

```
$ php --ini
```

If you can't fix your command line `php.ini` file, consider connecting to your MySQL server via `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.  When you use the IP address, PHP should attempt to connect via the network instead of a socket file.